# How to pass closure with parameters to a function? (Swift)

Tags: swift, closures

So I have a function that I need to execute when a condition is met, and if it's not, just wait 0.2 seconds, then try again (recursively).

```
func myFunction(_ str1: String? = nil, _str2: String? = nil)
{
    //whatever
}
```

(Note that I gave the arguments a default value, so I can call this function without specifying any parameters). Now, here's my 'delay' function:

```
func delay(_ function: @escaping (String?, String?) -> Void)
{
    if !myExternalCondition
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            self.delay(function)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        function()    //error
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error: *Missing argument for parameter #1 in call*

Honestly, I'd like the delay function to take in any type of closure, regardless of its arguments (amounts or types). Any help is appreciated ;)

Edit: in case it's not clear, I want to be able to take any closure (capture it with all of its parameters) and execute it when it's ready.

Comment: Don't **wait** for an *externalCondition*. That's a very bad practice

Comment: sorry @rmaddy, I copy-pasted from my code and I missed it. It's calling itself ( ```self.delay(function)```). @vadian, regardless of the 'bad practice', at this point I'm interested in understanding how to pass a closure with arguments to a function. How can I even access them (for instance, if inside `delay` function I wanted to read one of the closures params)?

Comment: "Honestly, I'd like the delay function to take in any type of closure, regardless of its arguments (amounts or types)." What would that mean? In your above code, what value do you expect `str1` to have? "Can call this function without specifying any parameters" is just a syntax convenience. Your delay function *does* expect two parameters.

Comment: @Rob What I meant is that I would like to avoid forcing my closure to have specific argument types. I think I should look at generics for that, though. @rmaddy You're right, that was my mistake, in my code I had a function with a similar name and it was calling that instead of `delay`. So is there a way to just execute the closure 'as-is' in the else-statement, with all of its parameters that were passed?

Comment: What parameters were passed? I think you're misunderstanding what a "closure" is. What calling syntax are you expecting to work here? Can you write the line that calls `delay`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how default parameters work. Default parameters are just a syntax helper. They make it easier to call the function directly in code, but they don't change the function itself. There's no way that you could support any number of parameters if they were actually required; you'd need to pass something.

So just expand this to make the syntax convenience explicit with an overload:

```
func myFunction(_ str1: String?, _str2: String?)
{
    //whatever
}

func myFunction() {
    myFunction(nil, nil)
}
```

And then you can call it.

```
func delay(_ function: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    if !myExternalCondition
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            self.delay(function)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        function()
    }
}
```

It's possible you've just misunderstood how closures work. With the above `delay`, the following is fine using your original definition of `myFunction` (with default parameters):

```
delay { myFunction() }
```

The following is also fine:

```
delay { myFunction("xyz") }
```

The point is that the *closure* has no parameters. You may be thinking of `myFunction` as the "closure" but that's not correct. The closure is the `{...}` part. If it had parameters, you'd expect a `x in` syntax or `$0` somewhere in it.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. I honestly don't know how I missed it. What I needed was to have `delay (_ function : @escaping ()->Void)` and then call it `delay{ self.function() }`. In my head I wasn't treating it like I normally treat closures, instead I was trying to have the delay function execute the closure, if that makes sense.